# How should questions about Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've tagged this question about Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare: [What are the requirements to get supply drops?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/190206/4797) - with [advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-warfare), similiar to the Call of Duty: Modern Warfare series tags [[modern-warfare]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare*). It has since been edited to also be tagged with [call-of-duty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty), and then just [call-of-duty-aw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-aw).

If we include the full game title: [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare)-  it won't fit the tag character limit (same as [call-of-duty-modern-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-modern-warfare)), so the tag must be shortened.

How should questions about Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare be tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This tag has been renamed to [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare)**.

Following the [length increase](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), this tag was renamed and synonimized on August 25<sup>th</sup>, 2017.

[image: Tag rename]

Answer (score 8):

I haven't been keeping up with the Call of Duty series in a few years (last played MW2), but I believe the general solution should roughly be:

If this is going to be another series of tied-together games, similar to Modern Warfare, and the common term is just going to be Advanced Warfare, your tagging (revision 2) was correct.

If this is going to be a standalone, or marketed heavily as part of the Call of Duty series, and thus isn't appropriate for splitting into its own tag, then none of the revisions are correct yet; we generally shorten the series title first when abbreviating, so [cod-advanced-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-advanced-warfare) would be preferred. See, e.g., the various mc-* tags for Minecraft mods with long names, tf2-* for Team Fortress 2 class tags, etc.

Comment: Is the a reason the old tags shouldn't be `cod-modern-warfare-X`?

Comment: Well, that's kinda my middle paragraph. The Modern Warfare series, at least for a while, were sorta marketed as being their own thing separate from CoD, except not always, and the name "Call of Duty" was gonna come off the second one entirely, except it didn't.

Comment: I can't find anything about Advanced Warfare being a series yet. So I went ahead and tagged the question with [tag:cod-advanced-warfare]. It seems that the game is being marketed with 'Call of Duty' in its title, e.g. [the game's title in its Steam page is 'Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare'](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209650/).